# function in loaded package doesn't appear in search path

Tags: r, package

I have a published package `cgwtools` which includes an overload of the `!` operator.  Here's the code from the source file `splatnd.r` :

```
`!` <- function (e1, e2) 
{
    call <- match.call()
    original <- function() {
        call[[1]] <- quote(base::`!`)
        return(eval(call, parent.frame(2)))
    }

    
    switch(paste(as.character(call[[2]]), sep = "", collapse = ""), 
        newdev = dev.new(width = 4.5, height = 4.5, restoreConsole = T), 
        qapla = cat("batlh tIn chav\n"), return(original()))
}
```

This is based on the neat tool in the `sos` package called `???` .  If I simply `source` the `!` code, it runs as expected.  In the past, at least prior to `R 3.2.x` , loading the package `cgwtools` let me run `!` as expected.  I recently set up both  versions 3.2.4 and 3.3.1 on a Windows 7 machine, and got an odd apparent failure to load.  Here's some console text, showing the searchpath before and after loading `cgwtools`

```
> getAnywhere(`!`)
A single object matching ‘!’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:base
  namespace:base
with value

function (x)  .Primitive("!")
> library(cgwtools)
> getAnywhere(`!`)
2 differing objects matching ‘!’ were found
in the following places
  package:base
  namespace:cgwtools
  namespace:base
```

By way of comparison, doing the same with the `sos` package returns what I'd expect:

```
> getAnywhere(`?`)
2 differing objects matching ‘?’ were found
in the following places
  package:sos
  package:utils
  namespace:utils
  namespace:sos
```

If I access the output, the correct source code is shown:

```
> getAnywhere(`!`)[2]
function (e1, e2) 
{
    call <- match.call()
    original <- function() {
        call[[1]] <- quote(base::`!`)
        return(eval(call, parent.frame(2)))
    }
    switch(paste(as.character(call[[2]]), sep = "", collapse = ""), 
        newdev = dev.new(width = 4.5, height = 4.5, restoreConsole = T), 
        qapla = cat("batlh tIn chav\n"), return(original()))
}
<environment: namespace:cgwtools>
```

But , as indicated by the lack of the text `package:cgwtools` , when I try to run, say  `!qapla` from the gui console,  I get the error message that `qapla` is not found, i.e. the `.Primitive` operator `!` was invoked.

So the question is:  why is the `!` function in the `cgwtools` package not being recognized after loading the package?   Did I do something dumb when building the package source, or did I find some bug in the CRAN builder?

Sub-question: I can't figure out any variant of the directed command `cgwtools::`'!'`qapla` that doesn't cause a parse error.

## edit

In response to alexis_laz 's query:

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:cgwtools"  "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:datasets"  "package:grDevices"
 [7] "package:lattice"   "package:sos"       "package:brew"     
[10] "package:utils"     "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[13] "package:base" 

> cgwtools:::'!'qapla
Error: unexpected symbol in "cgwtools:::'!'qapla"
```

And,

```
> get('!')(qapla)
Error: object 'qapla' not found
> get('!',2)(qapla)
Error: object 'qapla' not found
```

Suggesting again that "!" didn't get exported from `cgwtools` .
Note also that  -- see above for the items returned from

```
 getAnywhere(`!`)
```

I can pull the code:

```
> getAnywhere(`!`)[2](qapla)
batlh tIn chav
```

Comment: Is `"!"` exported? (you could try `cgwtools:::"!"(qapla)` for the second part)

Comment: @alexis_laz see updates. thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `"!"` be exported if it is to be used?

Comment: @alexis_laz . Of course -- the question is:  why **isn't** it?  I didn't do anything magic when building the package.

Comment: Perhaps, it is just the default `export`ing of `package.skeleton` (or another `export`ing pattern) that ignores `"!"` in namespace. You could, probably, add `export("!")` explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to @alexis_laz for his suggestions, I went back and looked at the default `NAMESPACE` file that `package.skeleton` generates.  The file contains the line
`exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`

Clearly I need to add an explicit `export('!')`  line to this file. (Plus the new requirements for explicit `import` of `base` packages per recent CRAN requirements,but that's a separate issue)

## edit

For the inexperienced (like me), be aware that, after changing the `NAMESPACE` file, one must rebuild the package.  Editing said file is insufficient.